# Json System.err: Unexpected character () at position 0. only from php

Tags: java, android, json

```
URL url = new URL(host);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
System.out.print(code);

if (code==200) {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    if (in != null) {
        String content = in.toString();
        System.out.print(content);
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        result = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
        System.out.print(jsonObject);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

When I have a host string like `http://www.example.com/json.txt` it all works fine, but when I have host string like `www.example.com/index.php?data=data&data2=data2` I get the following error:

> W/System.err: Unexpected character () at position 0.
>   I/System.out: 200java.io.BufferedInputStream@8bc189fpp = [0, 700, 250, 700]

My PHP output in browser looks fine, when I copy it to `json.txt` it also works fine.

I try to play with urlConnection POST, GET, RAW without luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was probly BOM in php json.

I do:

```
URL url = new URL(host);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.print(code);
            if(code==200){
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

                if (in != null) {


                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                        String line = "";

                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                            result += line;


                    result = result.substring(1);
                    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(result);
                    result=(String) jsonObject.get("name");
                    System.out.print(jsonObject);
                }
                in.close();
}
```

And it works.